# Angular 8 Form Array returns Cannot find control with path: 'variable -> 0'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

Im trying to create a dynamic table which will display data from an array of object. The table has an input per cell for editing the values. 
But its giving me an error of ***Cannot find control with path: 'variable -> 0'***

I have the following code

I add the dynamic form array like this

```
    this.form.addControl(property, new FormArray(properties));
```

The format of my array is like this

```
[
{
  header: 'header1',
  value: [FormControl 1, FormControl 2, FormControl 3]
},
{
  header: 'header2',
  value: [FormControl 1, FormControl 2, FormControl 3]
}
]
```

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
 <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let data of properties[0]?.value?.controls; let indx = index">
                            <td *ngFor="let item of properties">
                                <ng-container [formArrayName]="item.header">
                                    <input class="form-control" [formControlName]="indx" [value]="item.value?.controls[indx].value">
                                </ng-container>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
</tbody>
</form>
```

I already tried creating a getter for the form array like on the documentation, 
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArrayName

```
 get cities(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('cities') as FormArray;
  }
```

stackblitz link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tjkbt6

Error does not occur here in stackblitz but is occuring in my local

P.S The format for the array could still be changed if needed

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: Hello apologies for the late reply I already attached the stackblitz link to the question
The one in stackblitz doesnt return an error but on my local copy it does (weird)

Comment: sometimes is a problem at very early application, you can use generally a *ngIf to be sure the form is created: `<form *ngIf="form" [formGroup]="form">`

Comment: @Eliseo tried that, still didn't work